# Moving/rotating shapes in the vertex shader

Tags: opengl, 2d, shader, vertex-shader

I'm writing a program that draws a number of moving/rotating polygons using OpenGL. Each polygon has a location in world coordinates while its vertices are expressed in local coordinates (relative to polygon location). Each polygon also has a rotation.

The only way I can think of doing this is calculate vertex positions by translation/rotation in each frame and push them to the GPU be drawn, but I was wondering if this could be performed in the vertex shader.

I thought I might express vertex locations in local coordinates and then add location and rotation attributes to each vertex, but then it occurred to me that this won't be any better than pushing new vertex positions on each frame.

Should I do this kind of calculation on the CPU, or is there a way to do it efficiently in the vertex shader?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vertex shader is indeed responsible for transforming your geometry. However, the vertex shader is run for every single vertex of your scene. If you do transformations inside the vertex shader, you'll do the same calculation over and over again which yields the same result every time (as opposed to simply multiplying the model view projection matrix with the vertex coordinate). So in terms of efficiency you're best off doing that on the CPU side.

If the models are small, like in your case, I don't expect there to be too much of a difference, because you still have to set the coordinates where the polygons are supposed to be drawn somehow. In this case doing the calculations once on the CPU side is still the best, given that it does the calculation once independent of the vertex count of your polygons, as well as that it will probably result in clearer code since it's easier to see what you're doing.

Comment: So you think the best approach would be to calculate a transformation matrix for each polygon in each frame, transform all the vertices and then send them to the vertex shader. Is that right?

Comment: No, Just do the transformations on the model view matrix on the CPU side. You'll be doing the same work inside the vertex shader multiple times otherwise. The vertex shader can then do the coordinate transformations, because they are different on a vertex-by-vertex basis.

Comment: I have to ask, since I'm so new to OpenGL. Could the model, view, and projection matrices be set per vertex? I thought they are the same for the entire scene.

Comment: You constantly modify the modelview matrix through glTranslate(), glRotate() or glScale() and the projection matrix through the glFrustrum() or glOrtho() calls (given that you set the matrix mode they belong to first). Then they are the same until changed, and will thus apply to all geometry drawn with that version of the transformation matrices.

Comment: Ah, so I make a modification, draw one polygon, make another modification, another polygon, and so on. Is that right?

Comment: Yes indeed. You use glPushMatrix() and glPopMatrix() to stack matrices, so you can save and revert matrix states, respectively. I'd recommend looking at the [scene graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scene_graph) pattern, because it works really well with the way OpenGL does its transformations.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, I think I read glRotate and friends are deprecated in OpenGL 3.3. If that's right, what am I supposed to use instead? Uniform matrices set repeatedly perhaps?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54624/discussion-between-bartvbl-and-elektito).

Answer (score 0):

These calculations are usually done on CPU only. As doing them on CPU is efficient in general. your best shot is to send these rotation matrices in as uniform and do multiplication on GPU. Sending uniforms is not very expensive operation in general so u should be be worrying about that.

Comment: There is one rotation matrix per polygon, so uniforms don't seem to be the solution. Or are you suggesting I should send a uniform array or something?

Comment: yes ! i didnt notice that. Uniforms are not solution for you then.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal That's not correct actually. Uniforms can pass in transformation matrices. But indeed you'd need to set them for every single polygon (I assume you are working on a particle system?). But you'd have to do the same thing when just using transformation matrices. So either way you have to somehow get the transformation data into the vertex shader. The cleanest way should therefore be to use transformations on the CPU side.